# Django: Spelling Mismatch Despite not being written

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

There's a perplexing issue that I cannot resolve.

The `models.py` has :

```
class Meetings(models.Model):
    team_id =                   models.ForeignKey( Team )
    meeting_id =                models.AutoField( primary_key = True )    
    mentor_meeting_rating =     models.IntegerField( default = 0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(5)] )
    mentee_meeting_rating =     models.IntegerField( default = 0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(5)] )   
    meeting_date = models.DateTimeField( default = django.utils.timezone.now ,blank = True)
    TEL = 'Telephone'
    ONL = 'Online'
    F2F = 'Face to Face'
    MEETING_METHODS = (
        (TEL,'Telephone'), 
        (ONL,'Online' ),
        (F2F,'Face to Face'),
    )
    meeting = models.CharField( max_length = 15, 
                              choices = MEETING_METHODS,
                              default = F2F )
```

The `admin.py` has :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Mentor, Mentee, Team, Admin, Meetings, Goals
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Mentor)
admin.site.register(Mentee)
admin.site.register(Team)
admin.site.register(Meetings)
admin.site.register(Goals)
admin.site.register(Admin)
```

The `urls.py` is :

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^dream_site/', include('dream_site.urls')),
]
```

The `settings.py` has :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dream_site',
    'dream_chat',
)
```

Yet the Meetings has 2 's' in the Admin interface, I ran a grep command and it didn't show anywhere having "Meetingss".

I checked and double checked but I can't figure out why this is happening.

[image: Grep for "Meetings"]
[image: Grep for "Meetingss"]
[image: Why is it showing "Meetingss"]
[image: "Goalss" is also behaving similarly]

Comment: You should use singular names for your classes. An instance isn't a "meetings", it's a meeting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django automatically creates a plural of your classes name. This feature is, for example, used in the admin interface. Therefore you're seeing "Meetingss".

It is a good practice to name your classes with singular names (Meeting). If you want to keep your naming, you can override Django's plural creation in a class's Meta information:

```
class Meetings(models.Model):
    # your code here

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Meetings'
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural for more information.

Comment: Please consider upvoting http://stackoverflow.com/a/31628972/5057730, after several edits it is now the more complete answer!

Answer (score 2):

**Django admin by default, lists all the models as plurals i.e with an `'s'` at the end.**

So, Django adds an `'s'` in `Meetings`in the admin template. Now, since your model `Meetings` has an `s` at the end, its displayed as `Meetingss`.

**To control this behaviour, you can use [`verbose_name_plural`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural). It controls the plural name for the object.**

You can set the plural name for the object as per your choice. If it is not set, Django will add an `'s'` at the end.

As per [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.verbose_name_plural),

> If  isn’t given, Django will use `verbose_name` + "s".

You can specify the value for `verbose_name_plural` to `Meetings` in your `Meta` class like below:

```
class Meetings(models.Model):
    team_id =                   models.ForeignKey( Team )
    meeting_id =                models.AutoField( primary_key = True )    
    mentor_meeting_rating =     models.IntegerField( default = 0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(5)] )
    mentee_meeting_rating =     models.IntegerField( default = 0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(5)] )   
    meeting_date = models.DateTimeField( default = django.utils.timezone.now ,blank = True)
    TEL = 'Telephone'
    ONL = 'Online'
    F2F = 'Face to Face'
    MEETING_METHODS = (
        (TEL,'Telephone'), 
        (ONL,'Online' ),
        (F2F,'Face to Face'),
    )
    meeting = models.CharField( max_length = 15, 
                              choices = MEETING_METHODS,
                              default = F2F )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Meetings' # explicitly provide the verbose_plural_name
```

**Note: Use singular names for your classes**

You can control the model's verbose name by [`verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#verbose-name) argument.

As per `verbose_name` docs,

> A human-readable name for the object, **singular**:

```
class Meetings:

    ....
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Meeting'
```

This will also work in your case.

Comment: After several edits this is now the more complete answer! +1

Answer (score 0):

`Meetingss` is the plural form of `Meetings`, Django Admin takes the liberty to put extra 's' there for managing a list of model objects.

The same is happening with your `Goalss`

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is by using verbose name as defined above or you could simply define your model as 'Meeting' rather than 'Meetings' to resolve the issue